# Optimizing trigonometric function of multiple arguments

Tags: trigonometry, optimization

I have an equation which is a linear combination of `sin` and `cos` functions in n (in this particular case n = 3) different angles.

The $\alpha$ corresponds to the rotation respect the x-axis, the $\beta$ to the y-axis and finally the $\theta$ to the z-axis.

What I am trying to achieve is to rotate a "mask" in order to fit an image.

Image that you have a logo of say `BMW` and you want to rotate that logo in such a way that it fits the logo in an image of a car.

At the end of the day for each point $ \begin{pmatrix}a \\b \\c\end{pmatrix}  $ of an image will be transformed into.

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a\sin(\beta) - b\sin(\theta)\cos(\beta) + c\cos(\beta)\cos(\theta) \\
b(\sin(\alpha)\sin(\beta)\sin(\theta)) + a(\sin(\alpha)\sin(\beta)\cos(\theta)) - a(\sin(\alpha)\cos(\beta)) + c(\sin(\theta)\cos(\alpha)) + b(\cos(\alpha)\cos(\theta) \\
c(\sin(a)\sin(c)) + b(\sin(a)\cos(c)) + b(\sin(b)\sin(c)\cos(a)) - c(\sin(b)\cos(a)\cos(c)) + a(\cos(a)\cos(b))
\end{pmatrix}
$$

For the sake of simplicity lets call the new point $\begin{pmatrix} a'(\alpha, \beta, \theta) \\ b'(\alpha, \beta, \theta) \\ c'(\alpha, \beta, \theta) \end{pmatrix}$.

Now I want to find the angles that better fit my image.

The first idea that I got was a simple least square method.

So for each point in the image: $min((a'(\alpha, \beta, \theta) - i_1)^2 + (b'(\alpha, \beta, \theta) - i_2)^2 + (c'(\alpha, \beta, \theta) - i_3)^2)$ where $\begin{pmatrix} i_1 \\ i_2 \\ i_3 \end{pmatrix}$ are the point of the image of the car and $\begin{pmatrix} a'(\alpha, \beta, \theta) \\ b'(\alpha, \beta, \theta) \\ c'(\alpha, \beta, \theta) \end{pmatrix}$ are the point of the logo.

Suppose that a very small images has 128x128 pixel so I need something quite fast.

Comment: What do you mean by optimal ?

Comment: Sorry it is not an equation but it is an optimization problem. Let me edit.

Comment: You should read the 20+ year old literature on this problem.  Examples: "[Image matching for translation, rotation and uniform scaling by the Radon transform](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/723649/)" and "[Robust Image Registration Using Log-Polar Transform](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/d1d0/314ae9ddfdf2cd24ff29d0ef77e437bbf13f.pdf)".

Comment: @EricTowers Thanks so much, yours is exactly the kind of answer I was looking for, I must have used the wrong keyword for looking at it. If you answer I will mark your as best answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I can give you a couple of hints on how to attack this problem.

First you should notice that this can be split into three optimization problems that are all one variable.  In other words find the $\alpha$ that optimizes $2\sin(\alpha) + 2 \cos(\alpha)$ and that is the optimal $\alpha$ overall.  Do the same for the other variables $\beta$ and $\theta$.  This makes it considerably easier.

For any optimization problem with no constraints, you should take a derivative and set equal to zero.  Then you should find the second derivative to prove it is a local max or min.

To prove it is a global max or min, you need to to use the properties of the trig functions e.g. differentiable, bounded, periodic.

---

After OP edited the question

Now this problem makes sense (and is interesting).  Here are more suggestions.

You still have an unconstrained optimization problem that is differentiable.  However in the multivariate case, you take the gradient and set it equal to zero.  Then find the Hessian matrix and prove that it is positive definite or negative definite at those points in order to see if it is a local max or min. Since the Hessian will be $3\times 3$ then the calculation won't be too bad but you can also use CAS systems like Wolfram Alpha to do the dirty work for you.

I would also try some to do some simple (but tedious) trig formulas to simplify the problem.  You are taking the square of a sum of trig functions, there has to be somewhere where you can use $\sin^2(\alpha) + \cos^2(\alpha) = 1$ or other trig formulas.  I believe Wolfram Alpha would do the simplifying for you.

Comment: Sorry, I made my question way too easy, sorry you for wasting time. I edited it in order to try to express what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding one aspect of AWashburn's answer:

The set of optima (which means maxima and minima) of 
$$  p \cos(\alpha) + q \sin(\alpha)  $$ 
is 
$$  \left\{ \arctan\left(\frac{q}{\sqrt{p^2+q^2}}, \frac{p}{\sqrt{p^2+q^2}}\right),
\arctan\left(\frac{-q}{\sqrt{p^2+q^2}}, \frac{-p}{\sqrt{p^2+q^2}}\right)
\right\}  \text{.}  $$

This uses the two argument version of $\arctan$, where $\arctan(x,y)$ gives a representative of the subset of the solutions of $\tan(\alpha) = y/x$ lying in the same quadrant as $(x,y)$.  (The one argument version of $\arctan$ will only return angles in quadrants I and IV.  That is, in the context of the above, it assumes that the sign applies only to $y$, not to $x$.  To get angles in quadrants II and III, we must allow and track negative $x$s.)

Comment: Thank you Eric, unfortunately I made my original question way too easy, I edited it in order to try to express what I really need.